# Refactoring picking fields from one object and assigning them to other

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-2016

If I have `book` object with following structure

```
{title: string, author: string, genre: string, read: boolean}
```

and I have the `req.body` that has all the fields from `book` object **as well as few others**.

Is there a way to refactor following code to more concise?

```
book.title = req.body.title
book.author = req.body.author
book.genre = req.body.genre
book.read = req.body.read
```

Comment: You can try [Object.assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) to copy all properties from one object to another.

Comment: Why dont you send book in req.body at the first place i.e. req.body.book

Answer (score -2):

```
// req.body = { otherThing: 'something', title: 'ok', author: 'aut', genre: 'scifi', read: false, foo: 'bar', bar: 'foo' }

const { title, author, genre, read } = req.body
const book = { title, author, genre, read }

console.log(book) // { ... }
```

Comment: `req.body` has more then all properties from book object so this is falsely answer.

Comment: See update using destructuring assignment.